# Can't find PostgreSQL in Library (macOS 10.15.1) yet SHOW hba_file; points to library

Tags: postgresql, macos-catalina

I'm attempting to link Databox to PostgreSQL and following their directions here: https://databox.com/connect-postgresql-data-easy-steps

However at this step:

> Add created user access from Databox IP to our newly created database. Add the following to pg_hba.conf and reload the database

I'm having trouble. I look for the hba_file so that I can edit it using `SHOW hba_file;` which gives me the following path:

`/Library/PostgreSQL/12/data/pg_hba.conf`

Now here's the part I'm having the most trouble with. I go into terminal and `cd Library` then `ls -a` and there is no PostgreSQL listed. And trying to tab-complete with `Po` returns no results. if I try `cd PostgreSQL` I get the following:

`cd: no such file or directory: PostgreSQL`

It just isn't there. I have hidden files showing and it's just...not there. But `SHOW hba_file;` continues to point to the same path. What's going on?

Comment: It said `/Library`. Don't forget the slash.

Comment: Ah thanks, I feel dumb.